# My header is going up when scrolling i have already add the position sticky

Tags: html, css, header, frontend, overflow

```css
/* @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Noto+Serif&family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap"); */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Kanit&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,200&family=Noto+Serif&family=Oswald:wght@300;400&family=Roboto+Mono:ital,wght@0,500;1,400&family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,900&display=swap");

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: calibri;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  height: fit-content;
}

.container {
  max-width: 120rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

header {
  background-color: #3498db;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;

  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* width: 100%; */

  /* min-height: 100%; */
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 40rem;
  font-size: 2ren;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  place-items: center;

  /* height: 15vh;  */
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 2.2rem;
}

nav ul li {
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid transparent;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid #1b0058;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: "Noto Serif", serif;
}

.hero-section {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  background-image: url(../images/Red\ background.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.hero-section-data {
  padding-left: 7rem;
  padding-top: 7.5rem;
  padding-right: 5rem;
}

.hero-section .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  place-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 3rem 1rem;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.hero-section-data h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
.hero-section-data p {
  margin: 2rem 0;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.hero-section button {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.hero-section button:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
  /* transform: scale(1.2) translateY(10px); */
}

.hero-section .image img {
  width: 200rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 5rem;
}

.features-section {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  background-color: #9df9ef;
  width: 100%;
}

.features-section .container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.features-section h2 {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.features-section h3 {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.features-section h5 {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.features-section button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.features-section button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}

.features-watch img {
  width: 50rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -29rem;
  top: 29rem;
  right: 1rem;
}

.comfortable .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 30rem;
  gap: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  place-items: center;
}

.comfortable h3 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.comfortable button {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.comfortable button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}

.comfortable img {
  margin-top: 10rem;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.fitness {
  background-image: url(../images/fitness.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 7.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.fitness .container {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  padding: 10rem 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.fitness h3 {
  font-size: 6.2rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.fitness p {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.last-btn {
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.last-btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}

.stock-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5rem 0;
  gap: 3rem;
}

.stock img {
  width: 40rem;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.stock-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.stock-content h3 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.stock-content button {
  place-self: start;
}

.footer-upper {
  background-color: #4169e1;
  padding: 2.5rem;
}

.footer-upper .container {
  display: flex;
  color: black;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-upper h4 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  /* margin-top: -5px; */
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid #1b0058;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  top: -1rem;
}

.footer-upper ul {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.footer-lower {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #000080;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}

.menu-bar {
  display: none;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 40%;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }

  .menu-bar i {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
  }

  .menu-bar {
    display: block;
  }
  /* Footer */

  .footer-upper .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 2rem;
  }

  .footer-upper .footer-links {
    width: 15rem;
  }

  .hero-section-data p {
    font-size: 3rem;
    /* font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.2; */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .hero-section .container {
    display: flex;
    /* justify-content: space-between;
    place-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 3rem 1rem; */
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .logo {
    padding-left: 2rem;
  }
}

/* @media (max-width: 425px) {
  .features-watch img {
    margin-top: 20rem;
    top: 20rem;
  }
} */

@media (max-width: 1360px) {
  nav ul {
    padding-right: 2rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1305px) {
  nav ul {
    padding-right: 3rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Watch Website</title>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="Css/Style.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <!-- Font awesome link  -->
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a2e94f730a.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="container">
        <div class="logo">Watch</div>

        <div class="menu-bar">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
        </div>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#hero">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#features">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#connect">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#fitness">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- menu button  -->
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section class="hero-section" id="hero">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="hero-section-data">
            <h1>
              Get your watch <br />
              now!
            </h1>

            <p>
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error ex
              ullam in, officiis modi sequi adipisci sed inventore molestias
              numquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Accusantium, ex?
            </p>
            <button>Order Now</button>
          </div>
          <div class="image">
            <img src="images/smart_watch-removebg-preview.png" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="features-section" id="features">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="features-content">
            <h2>Presenting</h2>

            <h3>Apple Watch Series 9</h3>
            <h5>
              Presenting to you the most luxurious watch of the world with
              unlimited features, which makes you'r life more easier.Available
              in different colors- Features and much more. You can Detects if
              you’ve been in a severe car crash, automatically connects you to
              emergency services, and notifies your emergency contacts.
            </h5>
            <button>Visit More</button>
            <div class="features-watch">
              <img src="images/features watch.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="comfortable" id="comfortable">
        <div class="container">
          <h3>
            Makes Your Life More Comfortable And Get Acess To The Wonderfull
            Features
          </h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe earum
            ipsum facilis nemo excepturi quaerat blanditiis fugiat atque, eius
            quia libero nulla quis repellat, pariatur distinctio illo explicabo
            totam dolores.
          </p>
          <a href="#"> <button class="read-more">Read More</button></a>

          <img src="images/threewatch.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="fitness" id="connect">
        <div class="container">
          <h3>Get your watch today!</h3>
          <p>
            Connectivity on your terms. The ultimate wearables experience.<br />
            Always connected… and it’s beautiful.It’s time to step up your style
            with a smartwatch that looks great with every outfit.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="stock-section container" id="fitness">
        <div class="stock-img">
          <img src="images/stock.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="stock-content">
          <h3>In Stock!</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam<br />
            accusantium temporibus pariatur ab nemo,Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
            consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, debitis. Blanditiis libero ad
            animi nam dolorem provident suscipit labore eligendi.
          </p>
          <p>
            If you have any query about the "Apple Watch Series" so you can
            contact our team.
          </p>
          <hr />
          <button class="last-btn">Buy Now</button>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <section class="footer-upper">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="footer-links">
            <h4>Shop & Learn</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Features</li>
              <li>Pricing</li>
              <li>Info</li>
              <li>Apps</li>
              <li>Connection</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-links">
            <h4>Our Branches</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Pakistan</li>
              <li>India</li>
              <li>Usa</li>
              <li>Nepal</li>
              <li>Bangladesh</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-links">
            <h4>Why us?</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Genuine Products</li>
              <li>Accuracy</li>
              <li>Discounts</li>
              <li>Delivery</li>
              <li>Gift Cards</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-links">
            <h4>Brands</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Apple</li>
              <li>Mi</li>
              <li>Samsung</li>
              <li>Huawei</li>
              <li>Honor</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="footer-lower">
        <p>All rights reserved @AnasSiddiqui 2022</p>
      </section>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

My header is going up when scrolling. I have already add the position sticky. Its work fine for the desktop but when i switch on the mobile devices by clicking the inspect button when i scroll down the header goes up i am finding the answers since many days.
I want the header to go down with the scroll especially in mobile devices.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please help me i am beginer here